# How to convert a non-square matrix to a square matrix with R?

Tags: r

I have a network data and trying to analyze it. The problem is it has some missing rows or columns. I want to match rows and columns, so it can be a square matrix

My data looks like this:

```
  A B C D E
A 0 2 1 4 5 
B 1 0 2 4 2
D 2 4 0 2 2 
E 1 2 2 2 0
```

And I want to make it looks like this:

```
  A  B  C  D  E
A 0  2  1  4  5 
B 1  0  2  4  2 
C NA NA NA NA NA 
D 2  4  0  2  2 
E 1  2  2  2  0
```

As my data is very huge so I cannot do it by hands. It there any syntax to do it automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a `NA` matrix based on the unique column names and row names (assuming that it is symmetric) and then fill it by matching row names and column names in original dataset

```
un1 <- unique(sort(c(colnames(m1), rownames(m1))))
m2 <- matrix(NA, length(un1), length(un1), dimnames = list(un1, un1))
m2[row.names(m1), colnames(m1)] <- m1
m2
#   A  B  C  D  E
#A  0  2  1  4  5
#B  1  0  2  4  2
#C NA NA NA NA NA
#D  2  4  0  2  2
#E  1  2  2  2  0
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 
 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 0L), .Dim = 4:5, .Dimnames = list(c("A", 
 "B", "D", "E"), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the syntax. It seems like it works with your example, but names of column and row (first column and first row) in my data are numbers, so it's not working on my dataset (sorting seems weird). And the results show the values in original dataset don't go to new matrix. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: I somehow made a matrix with the same names of columns and rows. But if I run 'm2[row.names(m1), colnames(m1)] <- m1', it says 'Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, row.names(m1), colnames(m1), value = c(0L, 0L,  : 
  subscript out of bounds'. What does it mean?

Comment: @Jun-yeobKim  Without a small reproducible example (using dput) that shows the error, it is difficult to know the issue.